# JavaScript - D3 force layout highlight subtree

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I Have my data represented by d3 force layout. Some nodes are folded and some other not. What I want to highlight  sub node.  This is my file containing JavaScript and html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

      circle.node {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: #3182bd;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      line.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #9ecae1;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var w = 1060,
      h = 800,
      node,
      link,
      root, 
      t;
      var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1;

      var force = d3.layout.force()
      .on("tick", tick)
      .size([w, h]);

      var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
        root = {
          "name": "flare",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "analytics",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "cluster",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                    {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                    {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                    {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "graph",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                    {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                    {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                    {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                    {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "optimization",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "animate",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
                {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
                {
                  "name": "interpolate",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
                    {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
                    {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
                    {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
                    {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
                    {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
                    {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
                    {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
                    {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
                {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
                {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
                {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
                {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
                {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
                {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
                {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
                {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "data",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "converters",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
                    {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
                    {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
                    {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
                    {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
                {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
                {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
                {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
                {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
                {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "display",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
                {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
                {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
                {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "flex",
              "children": [
                {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "physics",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
                {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
                {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
                {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
                {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
                {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
                {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
                {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "query",
              "children": [
                {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
                {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
                {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
                {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
                {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
                {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
                {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
                {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
                {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
                {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
                {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
                {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
                {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
                {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
                {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
                {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
                {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
                {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
                {
                  "name": "methods",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "add", "size": 593},
                    {"name": "and", "size": 330},
                    {"name": "average", "size": 287},
                    {"name": "count", "size": 277},
                    {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
                    {"name": "div", "size": 595},
                    {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
                    {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
                    {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
                    {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
                    {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
                    {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
                    {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
                    {"name": "max", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "min", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
                    {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
                    {"name": "not", "size": 386},
                    {"name": "or", "size": 323},
                    {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "range", "size": 772},
                    {"name": "select", "size": 296},
                    {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
                    {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
                    {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
                    {"name": "update", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
                    {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                    {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                    {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
                {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
                {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
                {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
                {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
                {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
                {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
                {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
                {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
                {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "scale",
              "children": [
                {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
                {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
                {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
                {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
                {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
                {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
                {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
                {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
                {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
                {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "util",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
                {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
                {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
                {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
                {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
                {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
                {
                  "name": "heap",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
                    {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
                {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
                {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
                {
                  "name": "math",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
                    {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
                    {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
                {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
                {
                  "name": "palette",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
                    {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
                    {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
                    {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
                {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
                {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
                {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
                {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vis",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "axis",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
                    {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
                    {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
                    {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
                    {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "controls",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
                    {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
                    {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
                    {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
                    {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
                    {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
                    {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
                    {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
                    {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
                    {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
                    {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "data",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
                    {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
                    {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
                    {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
                    {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
                    {
                      "name": "render",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
                    {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
                    {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "events",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
                    {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
                    {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
                    {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "legend",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
                    {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
                    {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "operator",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "distortion",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "encoder",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "filter",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
                    {
                      "name": "label",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "layout",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
                    {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
                    {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
                    {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
                    {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
              ]
            }
          ]
        };





        function parseLevel(node, level) {
          node.level = level;
          if (typeof node.children !== 'undefined') {
            node.children.forEach(function(children) {
              parseLevel(children, level + 1);
            });
          }
        }

        parseLevel(root, 0);



       // console.log(JSON.stringify(root, null, 2));



      update();
      function toggleAll(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
          if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL){
            return;
          }
          toggle(d);
        }
      }
      // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
      root.children.forEach(toggleAll);


      update(root); 
      // });

      function update() {
        var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

        // Restart the force layout.
        force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .charge(-1000)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .friction(0.5)
        .start();

        // Update the links…
        link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links.
        link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        // Exit any old links.
        link.exit().remove();

        // Update the nodes…
        node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        node.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r",  "15")
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", mouseover)     
        .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        node.exit().remove();

        t = vis.selectAll(".t-node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        t.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "t-node")
        .attr("dx", "25px")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .text(function(d){return d.name + " " + (d.level ? d.level:'')});
        // .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        t.exit().remove();

      }

      function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        t.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); 

      }

      // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
      function color(d) {
        return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function mouseover(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update();
      }

      // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
      function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [], i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
          if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
          if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
          nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
      }

      function toggle(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want for example to color in red every link and node behind a particular node (can be selected by name). My example contains a node named `query 1`: I want to color in red every node that is accessible via `query 1` node. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a little recursion to pre-process the data adding a property on whether it's a child of "query":

```
  function isChildofQuery(children, value){
    children.forEach(function(d){
      d['isQChild'] = value;
      if (d.name === "query"){
        isChildofQuery(d.children, true);
      } else if (d.children){
        isChildofQuery(d.children, false);
      }
    })
  }
  isChildofQuery(root.children, false);
```

Then when you draw the links:

```
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
    .style("stroke", function(d){
      return d.target.isQChild ? "red" : "#9ecae1;";
    });
```

Full running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

      circle.node {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: #3182bd;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      line.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #9ecae1;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var w = 1060,
      h = 800,
      node,
      link,
      root, 
      t;
      var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1;

      var force = d3.layout.force()
      .on("tick", tick)
      .size([w, h]);

      var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
        root = {
          "name": "flare",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "analytics",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "cluster",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                    {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                    {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                    {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "graph",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                    {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                    {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                    {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                    {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "optimization",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "animate",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
                {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
                {
                  "name": "interpolate",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
                    {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
                    {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
                    {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
                    {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
                    {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
                    {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
                    {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
                    {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
                {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
                {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
                {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
                {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
                {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
                {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
                {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
                {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "data",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "converters",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
                    {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
                    {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
                    {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
                    {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
                {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
                {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
                {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
                {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
                {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "display",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
                {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
                {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
                {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "flex",
              "children": [
                {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "physics",
              "children": [
                {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
                {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
                {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
                {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
                {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
                {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
                {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
                {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "query",
              "children": [
                {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
                {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
                {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
                {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
                {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
                {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
                {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
                {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
                {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
                {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
                {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
                {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
                {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
                {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
                {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
                {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
                {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
                {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
                {
                  "name": "methods",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "add", "size": 593},
                    {"name": "and", "size": 330},
                    {"name": "average", "size": 287},
                    {"name": "count", "size": 277},
                    {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
                    {"name": "div", "size": 595},
                    {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
                    {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
                    {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
                    {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
                    {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
                    {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
                    {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
                    {"name": "max", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "min", "size": 283},
                    {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
                    {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
                    {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
                    {"name": "not", "size": 386},
                    {"name": "or", "size": 323},
                    {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "range", "size": 772},
                    {"name": "select", "size": 296},
                    {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
                    {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
                    {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
                    {"name": "update", "size": 307},
                    {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
                    {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                    {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                    {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
                {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
                {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
                {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
                {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
                {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
                {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
                {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
                {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
                {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "scale",
              "children": [
                {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
                {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
                {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
                {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
                {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
                {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
                {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
                {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
                {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
                {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "util",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
                {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
                {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
                {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
                {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
                {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
                {
                  "name": "heap",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
                    {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
                {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
                {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
                {
                  "name": "math",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
                    {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
                    {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
                {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
                {
                  "name": "palette",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
                    {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
                    {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
                    {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
                {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
                {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
                {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
                {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vis",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "axis",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
                    {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
                    {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
                    {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
                    {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "controls",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
                    {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
                    {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
                    {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
                    {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
                    {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
                    {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
                    {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
                    {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
                    {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
                    {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "data",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
                    {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
                    {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
                    {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
                    {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
                    {
                      "name": "render",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
                    {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
                    {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "events",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
                    {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
                    {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
                    {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "legend",
                  "children": [
                    {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
                    {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
                    {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "operator",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "distortion",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "encoder",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "filter",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
                    {
                      "name": "label",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "layout",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                      ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
                    {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
                    {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
                    {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
                    {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
                  ]
                },
                {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
              ]
            }
          ]
        };





        function parseLevel(node, level) {
          node.level = level;
          if (typeof node.children !== 'undefined') {
            node.children.forEach(function(children) {
              parseLevel(children, level + 1);
            });
          }
        }

        parseLevel(root, 0);

      

       function isChildofQuery(children, value){
        children.forEach(function(d){
          d['isQChild'] = value;
          if (d.name === "query"){
            isChildofQuery(d.children, true);
          } else if (d.children){
            isChildofQuery(d.children, false);
          }
        })
      }
      isChildofQuery(root.children, false);

      update();
      function toggleAll(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
          if (d.level < COLLAPSE_LEVEL){
            return;
          }
          toggle(d);
        }
      }
      // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
      root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      
      console.log(root)


      update(root); 
      // });

      function update() {
        var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

        // Restart the force layout.
        force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .charge(-1000)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .friction(0.5)
        .start();

        // Update the links…
        link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links.
        link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
        .style("stroke", function(d){
          return d.target.isQChild ? "red" : "#9ecae1;";
        })

        // Exit any old links.
        link.exit().remove();

        // Update the nodes…
        node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        node.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r",  "15")
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", mouseover)     
        .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        node.exit().remove();

        t = vis.selectAll(".t-node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", color);

        // Enter any new nodes.
        t.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "t-node")
        .attr("dx", "25px")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .text(function(d){return d.name + " " + (d.level ? d.level:'')});
        // .call(force.drag);

        // Exit any old nodes.
        t.exit().remove();

      }

      function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        t.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); 

      }

      // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
      function color(d) {
        return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function mouseover(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update();
      }

      // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
      function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [], i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
          if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
          if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
          nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
      }

      function toggle(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```